# ZeroMQ with PHP 7 in Ubuntu does not compile ("error: too many arguments to function")

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04, zeromq

I have upgraded php5.6 to php7, but zeromq extension makes a lot of problems. Where can I download the correct zmq.so file for php7? None of the official sites offer a version for php7 that works (I'm using apache2.4).

I've followed along the following tutorial: [How to install ZeroMQ](http://alexandervn.nl/2012/05/03/install-zeromq-php-ubuntu/).

The step "Installing ZeroMQ" is working fine, but the second step "Installing the PHP binding" is failing when I execute the command "make" with the following error:

```
"/home/puser/zeromq-4.1.4/php-zmq/zmq.c:2740:2: error: too many arguments to 
function 'zend_register_internal_class_ex' php_zmq_device_exception_sc_entry = 
zend_register_internal_class_ex(&ce_device_exception, php_zmq_exception_sc_entry, 
"ZMQException" TSRMLS_CC)  ^ In file included from /usr/include/php/20151012/main/php.h:40:
0, from /home/puser/zeromq-4.1.4/php-zmq/php_zmq.h:45,from /home/puser/zeromq-4.1.4/php-zmq
/zmq.c:31:/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend/zend_API.h:290:28: note: declared here ZEND_API 
zend_class_entry *zend_register_internal_class_ex(zend_class_entry *class_entry, 
zend_class_entry *parent_ce);"
```

When using php 5.6, this error does not appear. How to fix this?

### Edit

I 've found that ZeroMQ is currently "not working" with php7 from this post: [ZeroMQ installation](https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-the-php-zeromq-extension.html).  Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 11):

There is a beta version available via PECL that you can install, I have been working with it without any issues.

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
pecl install zmq-beta
```

If you get an error during install then you are most likely missing some dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dev libzmq-dev pkg-config
```

For MacOS, you can replace `apt-get` with `brew` and it should also work.

---

### Updated August 17, 2017

In newer versions of Ubuntu/Debian you can now do

```
sudo apt-get install php-zmq
```

Which is recommended over the previous method because it uses a newer version of the underlying ZeroMQ library and takes care of enabling the extension for you.

Comment: I've followed the official ZMQ docs to make, build, configure, whatever, to just get to a non-working ZMQ installation. Your answer gave me a working installation within 2 minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a new release with PHP 7: https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3

Comment: Yes, I have switched to amqp, it already got migrated for php7,  in case anyone else gets stucked

Answer (score 0):

I just published all the steps to install zmq and php-zmq on Debian or Ubuntu 16.04 with php7: [Install ZMQ and php-zmq extension on Debian or Ubuntu](https://eole-io.github.io/sandstone/install-zmq-php-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

I founded some version fully functional on php 7.0/7.1/7.2 
(not yet functional on php 7.3)

First, install the compiler package :

```
apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf pkg-config
```

After that, depends on your ubuntu version.

- 12.04/14.04/16.04 :

  apt-get -y install libzmq-dev
- 18.04 or more recent :

  apt-get -y install libzmq3-dev

X.Y dépends on your php version (7.0/7.1/7.2)

```
peclX.Y-sp install zmq-beta
```

When prompted with message :

> Please provide prefix of libzmq install
>   just press ENTER

After that :

```
bash -c "echo extension=zmq.so > /etc/phpX.Y-sp/conf.d/zmq.ini"
service phpX.Y-fpm-sp restart
```

That will should work.

Can verify the ZMQLIB version :

```
phpX.Y-sp -i | grep zmq
```