# Why ZEROMQ dont push data every time in Ratchet PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, real-time, zeromq, ratchet

I try build real-time application with RatchetPHP and ZeroMQ. When my clients subscribes to my WebSocket, I would want push some data to my Master. But not every request is pushed to my Master. If More specifically, every second request is pushed. When I run my script, and reload connection to websocket several times I ses following output:

```
Topic manager started!
Master started!
Opened connection!
Master: message handled by :NULL
Opened connection!
Opened connection!
Master: message handled by :NULL
Opened connection!
Opened connection!
Master: message handled by :NULL
Opened connection!
Opened connection!
Master: message handled by :NULL
Opened connection!
```

It means, that when I connect to my Websocket, only second connection push data to Master. And my code is below:

```
use React\EventLoop\LoopInterface;
use React\ZMQ\Context;
class Master
{
    const MASTER_PORT = 3333;

    public function __construct(LoopInterface $loop) {

        // Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
        $context = new Context($loop);
        $pull = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
        $pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:' . self::MASTER_PORT); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
        $pull->on('message', array($this, 'onMessage'));

        echo 'Master started!' . PHP_EOL;
    }


    public function onMessage($message) {

        echo 'Master: message handled :';
        var_dump($message);

    }

    // ...
}



use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServerInterface;
class Pusher implements WsServerInterface, WampServerInterface {

    const WEBSOCKET_PORT = 5555;

    /**
     * @var Topic[]
     */
    protected $topicLookup = array();

    protected $pushMaster;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Push to master
        $context = new \ZMQContext();
        $this->pushMaster = $context->getSocket(\ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'workers');
        $this->pushMaster->connect("tcp://localhost:" . Master::MASTER_PORT);

        echo 'Topic manager started!' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $conn->WAMP->subscriptions = new \SplObjectStorage;
        echo 'Opened connection!' . PHP_EOL;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
        echo 'Subscribe for ' . $topic . PHP_EOL;

        $topicObj = $this->getTopic($topic);

        if ($conn->WAMP->subscriptions->contains($topicObj)) {
            return;
        }


        $this->topicLookup[$topic]->add($conn);
        $conn->WAMP->subscriptions->attach($topicObj);

    }

   protected function getTopic($topic) {
       if (!array_key_exists($topic, $this->topicLookup)) {
           echo $topic . ' before send' . PHP_EOL;
           $this->push(json_encode(['action' => 'start', 'from' =>        $topic]));
           $this->topicLookup[$topic] = new Topic($topic);
       }

       return $this->topicLookup[$topic];
    }

    /**
     * @param string JSON'ified string we'll receive from ZeroMQ
     */
    public function onPush($entry) {
        $entryData = json_decode($entry, true);

        // If the lookup topic object isn't set there is no one to publish to
        if (!array_key_exists($entryData['symbol'], $this->topicLookup)) {
            return;
        }

        $topic = $this->topicLookup[$entryData['symbol']];

        // re-send the data to all the clients subscribed to that category
        $topic->broadcast($entryData);
    }
}



// script
 <?php
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new \app\Pusher();

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:' . \app\socket\Pusher::WEBSOCKET_PORT); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means the only client that can connect is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onPush'));

// Start master for listening messages from Pusher
//$master = new \app\daemon\Master($loop);

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8081, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new \app\socket\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Zmq is in beta (and has been for a WHILE). It's one of the reasons that I am considering moving away from Ratchet. As easy as Ratchet is to impliment, it relies on at least 2 beta libraries that I know of. And Zmq isn't compatible with PHP 7.0 either. So IMHO, Ratchet is not ready for "Production" use. Which is VERY sad. Ratchet is an awesome project.

Comment: I disagree with "*Zmq isn't compatible with PHP 7.0*", there is now a php7 support from zmq (in beta btw): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34476836/zeromq-with-php7-in-ubuntu-not-working